# async method is blocking UI thread on which it is executing

Tags: c#, async-await

Consider the following codes in Winform. When I clicked the button, I was expecting that the async method should not block UI thread on which it was executing.

However, I found out that button was frozen during async method calling...
If true, what is the point of async method? I am confused.

```
namespace WindowsFrmAsyn
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        async private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int contentlength = await AccessTheWebAsync();
            tbResult.Text =
                        string.Format("Length of the downloaded string: {0}.", contentlength);

            Debug.WriteLine(tbResult.Text);
        }    

        async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Call AccessTheWebAsync");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Debug.WriteLine("Call AccessTheWebAsync done");
            tbResult.Text = "I am in AccessTheWebAsync";
            return 1000;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler warning tells you exactly what's going on: since your `async` method does not ever `await`, it will run synchronously.

`Thread.Sleep` is a synchronous operation; if you want to fake an asynchronous operation, use `Task.Delay`:

```
async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
{
  Debug.WriteLine("Call AccessTheWebAsync");
  await Task.Delay(5000);
  Debug.WriteLine("Call AccessTheWebAsync done");
  tbResult.Text = "I am in AccessTheWebAsync";
  return 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently you're lacking await in the AccessTheWebAsync because you do not await anything so all code runs on the main thread. Async/await doesn't make the method run on a different thread except the part that you await.

The method must be something like this.

```
async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
{
     // Console writeline
     await Task.Delay(seconds);
     // Console WriteLine.
     return value;
}
```

So everything before and after an await inside the async method is run on the same thread the method has been called. Optionally you can use `ConfigureAwait` that is commonly used inside libraries so that everything after the await will occur at the same thread the await has been done.

Checkout http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/async-await-faq.aspx for some more information about async/await.

Answer (score 2):

When you write such code:

```
private async Task<int> DoStuffAsync()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This way you are doing things synchronously, because you are not using await expression.

Pay attention to the warning:

```
This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
```

Based on the warning suggestion you can correct it this way:

```
private async Task<int> DoStuffAsync()
{
    return await Task.Run<int>(() =>
    {
        return 0;
    });
}
```